# Where can I find good exercises about abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning, book-recommendation

I started to learn abstract algebra via YouTube playlists and am loving it so far. However, I am really struggling to find good exercises with answers that show the process to find the answer and don't just spoon-feed the answer. I tried finding books but many had answers to their exercices in other books that I couldn't find.

Comment: There's always the Schaum's Outlines series:  https://www.mhprofessional.com/schaum-s-outline-of-abstract-algebra-9780071403276-usa-group  ,  https://www.mhprofessional.com/schaum-s-outline-of-modern-abstract-algebra-9780070026551-usa  ,  https://www.mhprofessional.com/schaum-s-outline-of-group-theory-9780070041240-usa  .  The AMS Student Mathematical Library book _Problems in Abstract Algebra_  [ https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-82/ ] is _just_ challenging problems, but without solutions, so that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: All of Robert Ash's books have solutions to every exercise (as far as I know).

Comment: And for older books with exercises in algebra, see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366215/oldest-abstract-algebra-book-with-exercises). For the same question see also [quora](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-exercises-of-Abstract-Algebra-with-solutions). See also [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Basic-Abstract-Algebra-Exercises-Solutions/dp/9811252491). Moreover, have a look [here](https://math.ucr.edu/~mpierce/teaching/qual-algebra/fun/), or at similar sites.

Comment: In my opinion [Gallian](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Contemporary_Abstract_Algebra/JMUaCgAAQBAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0)'s exercises are good. And there are solutions for odd-numbered, some of which are very detailed (there is also a solutions manual with all solutions).

Comment: You may also try Dixon's [*Problems in Group Theory*](https://www.amazon.com/Problems-Group-Theory-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486459160). I have skimmed through the book only once. If I remember correctly, many problems in this book are related to actual research. Answers are given at the end of each chapter but sometimes they are not full solutions. It has a Dover reprint, which is dirt cheap.

Answer (score 1):

My first abstract algebra book was Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*.   It's full of good exercises. [Here's](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/John20B20FraleighA20First20Course20in20Abstract20Algebra20Solution20ManualAddison20Wesley202002.893279361) the solutions.

There's also *Abstract Algebra* by Herstein.  Here's the [solutions manual](https://www.scribd.com/doc/173230118/Herstein-Abstract-Algebra-Student-s-Solution-Manual).

When you get more advanced try *Topics in Algebra* by Herstein, *Algebra* by Hungerford,  or, when you get really advanced you have Lang's *Algebra* to look forward to.